# Master/Details with Griddle

Tags: datagrid, reactjs, selection, griddle

I'm working on a project where [Griddle](http://griddlegriddle.github.io/Griddle/quickstart.html) is used to show a list of item. I would like to support the typical master/details pattern and show more details for the selected row adjacent to my grid component. Looking through the API documentation I haven't been able to find any mention of how or whether row selection is supported but there are a few issues where selection is being discussed.

Are there undocumented APIs or any useful examples that could show how Griddle could be used as is or customized to support a single whole-row selection model in order to facilitate a master/details layout?

Related:

- [Does griddle support row\cell selection? #175](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle/issues/175)
- [Discussion about row selection #153](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle/issues/153)
- [selected rows are lost when the component re-render #151](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle/issues/151)
- [Row selection #144](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle/issues/144)
- [GriddleGriddle/griddle-selection-plugin](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/griddle-selection-plugin)